# DX11 created textures are white

Tags: windows-phone-8, directx, directx-11

I am trying to load a basic texture (1024x1024) and fill it with a solid color:

```
unsigned char *texArray = (unsigned char *)malloc(4 * 1024 * 1024 * sizeof(unsigned char));

for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024 * 4; i++) {
    texArray[i] = (unsigned char)125;
}

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
desc.Width = 1024;
desc.Height = 1024;
desc.MipLevels = desc.ArraySize = 1;
desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
desc.MiscFlags = 0;

ID3D11Texture2D *pTexture = NULL;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA TexInitData;
ZeroMemory(&TexInitData, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
TexInitData.pSysMem = texArray;
TexInitData.SysMemPitch = static_cast<UINT>( 1024*4 );
TexInitData.SysMemSlicePitch = static_cast<UINT>( 4 * 1024 * 1024 * sizeof(unsigned char) );

GraphicsBase.DXDevice->CreateTexture2D( &desc, &TexInitData, &pTexture );
GraphicsBase.DXDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(pTexture, NULL, &DXTextureContent);
```

When I use `DXTextureContent`, my textures appear all white. I am filling the texture with 125/125/125/125 for RGBA. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: @AaronHagan Thanks, I've updated the code (it wasn't the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the SysMemPitch of TexInitData for a start. A pitch of 0 is probably not what you're after and *could* perhaps be affecting the way it fills the texture. You'll probably want to set this member to (1024 * 4).

Comment: Hello Adam, I've updated my code to include `Pitch` and `SlicePitch`, it seems that the texture is still white.

Comment: Hello Adam, after further investigation, I found that   `desc.SampleDesc.Quality` was not set, so i would get random values in billions. After settings `desc.SampleDesc.Quality` to 0 it worked!

Comment: Ah yes, didn't spot that one, glad you figured it out. Although some values for SampleDesc.Quality other than 0 are valid, it would surprise me if the debug layer hadn't had something to say about it, make sure you always run with it turned on in Debug builds if you aren't already.

Answer (score 3):

You should always develop DX11 application with the `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` flag set at device creation.

With it, each D3D call are verbose as possible and your CreateTexture2D would had fail here with an invalid parameter error code.

D3D11 introduced some class helper to initialize resource description, with a `CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC`, you are guarantee to not have uninitialized member.